# changing images and text bits by clicks

Tags: javascript, html, image, text, dynamic

I am working with a script to change images in an HTML site when the user clicks on it. the script works a treat to have this kind of slideshow without the menu.

but now I want (from a design point of view) to have the image number and some image description underneath the image and they should (of course) as well change when somebody clicks to the image.

here is the script I used so far for having the image change. can somebody quickly help me with the text changing? ideally, it would get the text out of a list of string variables I define or it could also work to read the text from an external TXT file etc.

here is the code I use so far!

```
     <div id="content">
     <img src= "testbild01.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" style="float:left" id="imageisabutton" />



        <script type="text/javascript">
        var images = ['testbild01.jpg', 'testbild02.jpg', 'testbild02.jpg'],
            i = 0;

        // preload
        for (var j=images.length; j--;) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = images[j];
        }

        // event handler
        document.getElementById('imageisabutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.src = images[i >= images.length - 1 ? i = 0 : ++i];
        }, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: you're right - sorry was early in the morning (thx)

Answer (score 0):

Add another array for description, such as

```
var descriptions = ['description 1', 'description 2', 'description 3'],
```

Add a new element for the description, below the image, such as

```
<div id="mydescription"></div>
```

Add the following code after `this.src = ...`

```
document.getElementById('mydescription').innerHTML = i + ' ' + descriptions[i];
```

Comment: thx for the quick answer.. it still doesnt work (only image changes) although i think the 2nd array idea looks good. i updated the code maybe you have an idea whats going wrong?

Comment: `Description` defined as `mydescriptions` but used as `desc` which not defined and should be NaN

Answer (score 0):

like this it works! thx

```
     <div id="content">

     <center> 
     <c id='numbers'>image 1/3</c>
     <br />


     <img src= "testbild01.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" style="float:left" id="myButton" />

     <script type="text/javascript">

    var images = [
    'testbild01.jpg',
    'testbild02.jpg',
    'testbild03.jpg'
    ],
    i = 0;

    var mydescriptions = [
    'text 1, 
    'text 2, 
    'text 2'
    ],
    i = 0;


    // preload
    for (var j=images.length; j--;) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = images[j];
    }

    // event handler
    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.src =              
        images[i >= images.length - 1 ? i = 0 : ++i];

    document.getElementById('mydescriptions').innerHTML =  mydescriptions[i];
    document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML = 'image ' + (i+1) + '/' + (j+4);

    }, false);                                          


     </script> 

     <br />
     <c id='mydescriptions'>click image to move through slideshow</c>

     </center>
```

Comment: The second array name is 'mydescriptions' and not 'desc'. 
you have typo error in line   document.getElementById('mydescriptions').innerHTML = x + ' ' + desc[i];

instead use the below

document.getElementById('mydescriptions').innerHTML = (i+1) + ' ' + mydescriptions[i];

Comment: Variable defined as `mydescriptions` but used as `desc` which not defined and should be NaN